# Is it possible to add an eventlistener on a DIV?

Tags: javascript, css, events, touch, dom-events

I know this function:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    alert(event.touches.length);
}, false);
```

But is it possible to add this to a div? Example:

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        alert(event.touches.length);
    }, false);
```

I haven't tested it yet, maybe some of you know if it works?

Comment: Yes. Possible. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/domtricks2/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yeah, that's how you do it.

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, false);
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, false);

function touchHandler(e) {
  if (e.type == "touchstart") {
    alert("You touched the screen!");
  } else if (e.type == "touchmove") {
    alert("You moved your finger!");
  } else if (e.type == "touchend" || e.type == "touchcancel") {
    alert("You removed your finger from the screen!");
  }
}
```

Or with jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $("#div").bind("touchstart", function (event) {
    alert(event.touches.length);
  });
});
```

Comment: JQuery's bind also takes the third Boolean parameter to handle bubbling. The default is the equivalent of false in the javascript code too so for consistency you should have it either in both listings or none.

Answer (score 0):

The other way round if you are not using addEventListener, probably a alternative to get control over ID.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#container1').on("contextmenu", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, let's assume you have to insert text in **h1** element when a user clicks on the button. It's pretty easy to bind HTML's specific element to **addEventListener()** method

```
<button id="button">Show me</button>


<h1 id="name"></h1>


document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
});
```