# Detect onclick of class using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am adding a class dynamically to some elements. And i need to get the innerHTML of the clicked element where the added class is present. Can anyone have any idea of how to get the innerhtml with refer to class?

Please note that i don't want to use any Javascript libraries like jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589863/362536

Comment: Look here maybe helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164053/is-it-possible-to-add-an-eventlistener-on-a-div][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164053/is-it-possible-to-add-an-eventlistener-on-a-div

Comment: @Brad It is only working for the immediate element. For eg. If i have a div inside `myclass` which is having some other class name, than it is not triggering.

Comment: @GTSouza Those solutions are given with refernce to `id`. But i need that for **class**.

Comment: @nnnnnn I want to do something when both <i>x</i> or any of its descendent is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    var clickedEl = window.event ? event.srcElement : e.target;
    while (clickedEl != null) {
        if (clickedEl.className
            && (" " + clickedEl.className + " ").indexOf(" yourclass ") != -1) {
            // do something, e.g.,
            alert("Element with class was clicked");
            return;
        }
        clickedEl = clickedEl.parentNode;
    }
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3qChA/

This will do "something" (in my example show an alert) when any element with class "yourclass" is clicked, or when any descendant element of an element with "yourclass" is clicked. Obviously you can replace the hard-coded "yourclass" with a variable as appropriate.